# Invoking an async action creator helper with redux-thunk

Tags: javascript, axios, redux-thunk

I'm trying to invoke a helper method for two async action creators, but I'm unsure why I can't do so. The function assigned to `signUpOrSignIn` should get invoked by both `signUp` and`signIn`. These are in the same file. I'm thinking the issue involves either my function declaration or handling of `async dispatch`. Would appreciate your feedback. Thanks!

```
import axios from "axios";
import * as types from "./types";

const signUpOrSignIn = (path, email, password, history) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(path, { email, password });
    history.push("/dashboard");
    dispatch({ type: types.DID_SIGN_IN, payload: res });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({ type: types.DID_SIGN_IN, payload: err.response });
  }
};

export const signUp = (email, password, history) => async dispatch => {
  signUpOrSignIn("/users", email, password, history);
};

export const signIn = (email, password, history) => async dispatch => {
  signUpOrSignIn("/users/login", email, password, history);
};
```

Comment: Where do you invoke `signIn` or `signup`?

Comment: In a handler inside a React component. I know that `signIn` and `signUp` are being invoked, but neither are invoking `signUpOrSignIn`.

Comment: Can you try doing `return signUpOrSignIn("/users", email, password, history);` in both the function declarations.
You are using `{}` syntax in arrow function, but not returning anything.

Comment: Just tried with no luck.

Comment: Can you try removing `async dispatch` from `signUp` and `signIn`. 
They both just return a function. You are not using `dispatch` anyway in them. 
I think that is why `signUporSignIn` is not getting invoked.

If you do not want to remove it, then try invoking them like this `signUp(params)()` `signIn(params)()`

Comment: Removing `async dispatch` from `signUp` throws `Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.' The stack trace points to my invocation method in my React component handler.

Comment: Yes that is my point. `signUp` and `signIn` are not really actions?
They are action creators. This error is coming because these functions are getting passed as actions in your code.
Can you add some code of your react component as well, where you invoke them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211042/discussion-between-utsav-patel-and-chicobermuda).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `signUp` or `signIn` intend to just return the `signUpOrSignIn`.

You can remove `async dispatch`.

Like so:

```
export const signUp = (email, password, history) => signUpOrSignIn("/users", email, password, history);

export const signIn = (email, password, history) => signUpOrSignIn("/users/login", email, password, history);
```